# Are there compiler optimisations for methods of a templated class that don't use the template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-optimization

e.g.

```
template< class T >
class Foo
{
public:
    float MethodUseOfT()
    {
        return m_bar.CalculateSomething();
    }
    float MethodNoUseOfT()
    {
        float blah(0.f);
        ...
        return blah;
    }

private:
    T m_bar;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    float CalculateSomething();
}
```

If someone makes a `Foo<Bar>`, how is this managed by most compilers; will they, for example, generally realise `MethodNoUseOfT` doesn't reference the template argument and use that information to reduce the size of the generated machine-code?

Additionally, if the contents of `MethodUseOfT` is large and only has a single line referencing `T`, will compilers again try to reuse the machine code generated for the rest of the method?

Comment: I don't see `MethodUseOfT` actually *using* `T`? Or any use of `T` in general.

Comment: As for your problem, modern compilers are usually very good when it comes to optimizations. But the only way to know for sure is to actually *examine* the generated code.

Comment: edit: Thanks. Sorry, m_bar is of type T now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe.

Microsoft C++ has the option to merge identical functions (and of course `Foo<int>::MethodNoUseOfT()` will be identical to `Foo<double>::MethodNoUseOfT()`).

In general, this option is not standards conforming (because two normal functions that are generated from a function template are required to have different addresses, even if they are otherwise identical).  However this doesn't apply in this case, because there is no way to obtain the address of a member function (a pointer-to-member-function is very different from, and much more complicated than, an address) - so the linker might be able to do it.

As noted in the comments, the only way to be sure is to inspect the output of your compiler+linker.

The easy way to be sure, is to write something like:

```
class FooBase
{
public:
    float MethodNoUseOfT()
    {
        float blah(0.f);
        ...
        return blah;
    }
};

template< class T >
class Foo : public FooBase
{
public:
    float MethodUseOfT()
    {
        return m_bar.CalculateSomething();
    }

private:
    T m_bar;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    float CalculateSomething();
}
```

If you do this, you can even move the implementation of `MethodNoUseOfT` into a CPP file.

Answer (score 0):

Only if inlined; otherwise, since the symbols are mangled, they must be separate machine code blocks.

Comment: Note that template member functions pretty much *have* to be inlined unless you use explicit instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

The important part is 14.7.1 Implicit instantiation. "the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist. "

In other words, the "optimization" which you presume is in fact mandatory behavior for implicit instantiations. For explicit instantiations, the compiler will compile all members (after all, that's the point of explicit instantiation). The linker can still eliminate unused functions, though.

No compiler will attempt to reuse half a template method. That would require an extremely complex analysis, which would swamp any time saved in generating code.